# How to change colors of a Java Buffered Image

Tags: java, java-2d

I have a JavaBufferedImage.  The foreground is Black and the background is transparent.  I would like to recolor the image as Red.

I have read through other people's postings on this and tried using this code, but my Image winds up completey transparent when I run it.

Does anyone have any ideas?  I am new to the Java 2D Image processing library.  Thanks.

```
    imageIcon= new ImageIcon(getImageURL("/ImagesGun/GunBase.png"));
    gunBaseImage= Utilities.toBufferedImage(imageIcon.getImage());

    int red = 0x00ff0000;
    int green = 0x0000ff00;
    int blue = 0x000000ff;

    int width = gunBaseImage.getWidth();
    int height = gunBaseImage.getHeight();

    //Loop through the image and set the color to red
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            long pixel = gunBaseImage.getRGB(x, y);
            if(pixel != 0){
                red = 0x00ff0000;

                gunBaseImage.setRGB(x,y,red);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: calling getRGB and setRGB for each pixel is going to be slow, because these methods are trying to do a full color space conversion. For image processing it is better to get access to the int array behind the BufferedImage.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a fully transparent value of red. The first entry in the color definition is the alpha value. If you want a fully opaque color you need to use ff as the first value. Therefore your red should be 0xffff0000, your green 0xff00ff00 and so on. This also means that black is ff000000.

Comment: This is true.  I think that, if he wants to keep his opacity intact, he must mask that bit and deal with the value of the color itself, which means he needs to change his `if(pixel !=0)` check, right?  Then, inside his `if()` block, he needs to do a bitwise AND operation to add the original opacity to the color he wants.

Comment: My thoughts exactly @hfontanez. That's why I mentioned that opaque black is 0xff000000 so that he can do `if(pixel != 0xff000000)`.

Comment: @user1104028 Don't forget to accept Matthew's answer by clicking the star.